# Prototype make option in select be selected by provided value

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

populated by options (country list) using Protype:

```
for (var i = 0; i < j.length; ++i) {
            var opt = new Element('option', {value:j[i].country})
            opt.innerHTML = j[i].country_name;            
            country.appendChild(opt);
}
```

now i need to make option to be selected by value, somethhing like

```
function selectByValue(countryCode) {
   // make option selected where option value == countryCode
}
```

how to do it with Prototype?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('country').value=countryCode
```

Comment: Strange, 
document.getElementById('country').value=countryCode
alert(document.getElementById('country').value)
alerts valid "countryCode", but in combobox the old (first) value is still selected, why?

Comment: Ok, found the problem, it doesnt work when <select> is inside invisible div.

Answer (score 7):

To answer your question, "ho do you do it with Prototype" more directly, change:

```
document.getElementById('country').value=countryCode
```

to...

```
$('country').value = countryCode;
```

They both do the same thing, though.